# Is is possible to do an end-run around generics covariance in C# < 4 in this hypothetical situation?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, dispatch

Suppose I have a small inheritance hierarchy of Animals:

```
public interface IAnimal {
    string Speak();
}

public class Animal : IAnimal {
    public Animal() {}
    public string Speak() {
        return "[Animal] Growl!";
    }
}

public class Ape : IAnimal {
    public string Speak() {
        return "[Ape] Rawrrrrrrr!";
    }
}

public class Bat : IAnimal {
    public string Speak() {
        return "[Bat] Screeeeeee!";
    }
}
```

Next, here's an interface offering a way to turn `strings` into `IAnimals`.

```
public interface ITransmogrifier<T> where T : IAnimal {
    T Transmogrify(string s);
}
```

And finally, here's one strategy for doing that:

```
public class Transmogrifier<T> : ITransmogrifier<T> where T : IAnimal, new() {
    public T Transmogrify(string s) {
        T t = default(T);
        if (typeof(T).Name == s)
            t = new T();
        return t;
    }
}
```

Now, the question. Is it possible to replace the sections marked [1], [2], and [3] such that this program will compile and run correctly? If you can't do it without touching parts other than [1], [2], and [3], can you still get an `IAnimal` out of each instance of a `Transmogrifier` in a collection containing arbitrary implementations of an IAnimal? Can you even form such a collection to begin with?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t = new Transmogrifier<Ape>();
        Ape a = t.Transmogrify("Ape");
        Console.WriteLine(a.Speak());  // Works!

        // But can we make an arbitrary collection of such animals?
        var list = new List<Transmogrifier< [1] >>() {
            // [2]
        };

        // And how about we call Transmogrify() on each one?
        foreach (/* [3] */ transmogrifier in list) {
            IAnimal ia = transmogrifier.Transmogrify("Bat");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, since there is no type relationship between `Transmorgifier<Ape>` and `Transmorgifier<Bat>` so you can't put them in the same generic list (except `List<object>`). The obvious solution is just to make `ITransmorgifier` non-generic:

```
public interface ITransmogrifier
{
    IAnimal Transmogrify(string s);
}
```

Then you could have

```
var list = new List<ITransmogrifier>() {
    new Transmorgifier<Ape>(), new Transmorgifier<Bat>() ...
};
```

Comment: I suspected as much. I was hoping there'd be some trickery I could do with `.Cast<T>`, but I guess not.

Answer (score 4):

Lee is correct.

As you imply by your question, you can do this in C# 4 by marking ITransmogrifier as covariant ("out") in T. You can then make a `List<ITransmogrifier<IAnimal>>` and put a `Transmogrifier<Bat>` into that list.

Comment: Indeedy, I'm using `in`/`out` with reckless and gleeful abandon in C# 4. Immensely useful.